# PostgreSQL stored procedure error

Tags: postgresql, stored-procedures

I have a stored procedure:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION postalcode_lookup(ccode character(6))
RETURNS SETOF postalcode AS $BODY$
BEGIN
    WITH RECURSIVE tblParent AS 
    (
        SELECT * 
        FROM postalcode 
        WHERE postalcode.code = ccode

        UNION ALL 

        SELECT postalcode.* 
        FROM postalcode  
        JOIN tblParent ON postalcode.code = tblParent.parent
    )
    SELECT * FROM tblParent;

END;$BODY$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Compile successfully but when running I have

> error: query has no destination for result data;SQL state: 42601;
>
> Hint:> If you want to discard the results of a SELECT, use PERFORM
> instead.  Context: PL/pgSQL function postalcode_lookup(character) line
> 3 at SQL statement

Please help me fix. Many thanks.

Comment: [RETURN NEXT and RETURN QUERY](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpgsql-control-structures.html#AEN62624)

Answer (score 0):

In case of Function we have to return values

if you we write function as follow we can get desired results

```
    CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION postalcode_lookup(ccode character(6))
    RETURNS refcursor AS $BODY$
    DECLARE 
    cur_postalcode refcursor;
    BEGIN
Open cur_postalcode for
        WITH RECURSIVE tblParent AS 
        (
            SELECT * 
            FROM postalcode 
            WHERE postalcode.code = ccode

            UNION ALL 

            SELECT postalcode.* 
            FROM postalcode  
            JOIN tblParent ON postalcode.code = tblParent.parent
        )
        SELECT * FROM tblParent;
    return cur_postalcode;

    END;$BODY$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

on executing this function, you will get a cursor. to get values from cursor run given query.

```
SELECT postalcode_lookup(--ccode);

fetch all "<unnamed portal 1>";
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Returning a cursor might work, but is far more complicated to work with then a simple `return query ...`

Comment: I create as you descibed above but get error ERROR:  syntax error at or near "Open"
LINE 16: Open cur_postalcode for
         ^
********** Error **********

ERROR: syntax error at or near "Open"
SQL state: 42601
Character: 412

Comment: the resultset is very strange. Anyway, thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: Edited the answer to get required `resultset` on executing function

Comment: @anhdv: the result set is "strange" because it's a refcursor. That is not easy to handle. A PL/pgSQL function should use `RETURN QUERY` if you want to easily use the result inside a `select`  statement.